# how to create a set of panels in vb.net using for loop and then setting the name, size and location?

Tags: vb.net

```
If dgvstall.RowCount > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To x
        Dim Panel As New Panel
        Dim xloc As String = dgvstall.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        Dim yloc As String = dgvstall.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        Dim xsize As String = dgvstall.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        Dim ysize As String = dgvstall.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        Panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Panel.Location = New Point(xloc, yloc)
        Panel.Size = New Point(xsize, ysize)
        Me.Controls.Add(Panel)
    Next
End If
```

what i want to achieve is to create a set of panels depending on rowcount then set the name, size and location

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you currently have? You're already setting the `Size` and `Location` properties so why can't you set the `Name` property in a similar way?

Comment: Also, why do you want to create `Panels` in the first place?  It may not even be the best option, depending on what you're trying to achieve.  In short, give us some background for the problem.

Comment: You're repeating `dgvstall.CurrentCellAddress.Y` for both the X & Y for both location & size. That seems wrong.

Comment: im trying to create a system that will pinpoint location of each stall in a public market for a school requirement and then set the name of tenants on every panel when hovered. sorry im new to vb.net and stackoverflow as well.

Comment: @Enigmativity, how do i achieve creating a set of panels, then set individual properties using for loop?

Comment: @jmcilhinney only one panel(the last one) is appearing, but if i msgbox the panelnames, they are equal to rowcount.

Comment: Have you debugged your code?  I'll wager not, so that's what you should do first.  If you don't know how, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). My guess would be that you are using the same `Size` and `Location` for each control so you can only see one of them but debugging will allow you to see EXACTLY what is happening as the code executes.

Comment: @NotKapier - Your code looks fine except for turning the strings like `xloc` into a `Float`. Is that the problem that you're having? Oh, no, you haven't got `Option Strict On` set, have you?

Comment: thanks @Enigmativity  panels are there,names,locations and sizes as well(they are at least displayed in the msgbox), but they are not being displayed on the form,any suggestion?

Comment: @NotKapier - What msgbox? What are the `Size` and `Point` locations that are being set? And do you have `Option Strict On` set in your code?

Comment: What is x? Why a panel? The point constructor takes (Double, Double) not strings. The size property is not a point. It is a Structure consisting of Height, Width expressed as (Integer, Integer) again, not strings.